# How would I merge these 3 pipes with this corner?

Tags: modeling

These are my 3 pipes
[image]

I want to merge them together and have this look at its corner

[image]

How would I achieve this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** Probably much easier since 2.8 with the new *Mirror "Bisect"* option

Former answer:

I've found an answer for a basic 3 cylinders shape, but it looks like it's not exactly what you're looking for. That said, I'm not sure your drawing means anything in 3D. Anyway, perhaps my solution will help?

- Create a cylinder with *Cap Fill Type* > *Ngon*.
- In *Edit* mode, rotate it and move its cap to the origin with the *Snap to Grid* option (or put the 3D Cursor on the center of the scene, choose the 3D Cursor as Pivot, and <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>).
- In *Object* mode duplicate the cylinder once and presse <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Rotate the duplication 120° on the Z axis.
- Duplicate and rotate again. Now you have a 3 branches star.
- Join the 3 cylinders with 2 *Booleans* modifiers / *Union* mode.
- Apply the *Booleans*.
- Select all and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.
- Delete the inner edges.
- Delete the useless vertices.
- If you want to extend the cylinders length, you can select all the caps and use <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> > *Individual Faces*, or select each cap and move it on its normal axis.

[image]